# Define is not defined

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, jasmine-jquery

I really really want to get jasmine-jquery working with jasmine. Not only will it make manipulating the DOM a breeze but it will also provide me with a ton of useful matchers.

However, it gives me this error when I try to start my spec runner:

```
 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define
  at /.../app/vendor/assets/bower_components/jquery/src/jquery.js:37
```

Any idea what this means? I'm using Karma to run my specs. Here's my unit.js config:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '..',

    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    urlRoot: '/_karma_/',

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'vendor/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'vendor/assets/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'vendor/assets/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'vendor/assets/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
        'vendor/assets/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
        'vendor/assets/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
        'vendor/assets/bower_components/jquery/src/jquery.js', // added this first
        'vendor/assets/jasmine-jquery.js',                     // and then this...
        'vendor/assets/bower_components/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js',
        'app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee',
        'app/assets/javascripts/**/**',
        'spec/javascripts/**/*'
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [

    ],


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
    reporters: ['dots'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        autoWatch: true,

    plugins : [
        'jasmine-given',
        'requirejs',
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-firefox-launcher',
        'karma-opera-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-ng-scenario',
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
        'karma-coffee-preprocessor'
    ],

    browsers: ['PhantomJS','Chrome','Firefox','Opera'],


    // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
    captureTimeout: 60000,


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false,

    // Preprocessors
    preprocessors: {
        '/**/*.coffee':'coffee',
        '**/*.slim': ['slim', 'ng-html2js']
    }
    /*
    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      stripPrefix: 'app/assets/templates/',
      stripSufix: '.slim'
    }
    */
  });
```

All I've done, [per the instructions](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) is download jquery, download jasmine-jquery and then require them in Karma's spec file:

```
files: [
        'vendor/assets/bower_components/jquery/src/jquery.js', // added this first
        'vendor/assets/jasmine-jquery.js',                     // and then this...
        ]
```

But jquery keeps giving me that undefined is not defined error.

I get no warnings from karma about the paths being wrong.

So how do I get jasmine-jquery working?

Could requirejs have something to do with getting it working?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [the response to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671089/cant-find-variable-loadfixtures/27806497#27806497) you need to make sure you npm download jasmine-query.
You'll need to change the following in you `karma.conf.js`:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine-jquery', 'jasmine']
```